# How to query records where one field greater than another by x days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | expiry     | timestamp  |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2018-11-29 | 2018-11-01 |
|  2 | 2018-12-27 | 2018-11-01 |
|  3 | 2019-01-31 | 2018-11-01 |
|  4 | 2018-11-29 | 2018-11-01 |
|  5 | 2018-12-27 | 2018-11-01 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

How can I query all records for which `expiry` is less than 30 days from `timestamp`? i.e.

```
timestamp + 30 days > expiry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
where expiry < timestamp + interval 30 day
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP , INTERVAL 30 DAY) > expiry;
```